# Find next unique array combination

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have an array

```
let arr = [a, b, c];
```

The unique combinations for the array would be [a], [b], [c], [a, b], [a, c], [b, c] and [a, b, c].

Using indexes it would be [0], [1], [2], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2] and [0, 1, 2].

Does anyone know a good way of dynamicly getting the next unique array combination given the indexes of the current combination as input.

For example

```
let a = foo(arr, [1]);
// a = [c] or [2]

let b = foo(arr, [2]);
// b = [a, b] or [0, 1]
```

And by dynamicly I mean that I dont want to generate all possible unique combinations and then iterate that array.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I made another try solving this and ended up with this. Maybe I should rephrase the question and ask for possible improvements for the solution.

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

let input = [0];

for (let i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
  input = foo(arr, input);
  console.log(input.map(index => arr[index]));
}

function foo(a, b) {
  let i = b.length - 1;
  while (i >= 0) {
    if (b[i] < a.length - (b.length - i)) {
      b[i]++;
      break;
    }
    i--;
  }
  if (i === -1) {
    b.unshift(0);
    i++
  }
  if (b.length > a.length) {
    return [0];
  }
  for (let j = i + 1; j < b.length; j++) {
    b[j] = b[j - 1] + 1;
  }
  return b;
}
```

Comment: btw, why is the position in an array? what have you tried?

Comment: the input argument would often represent multiple positions in the original array. Thats why its an array.

Comment: All the "combinations" (they're not _combinations_, they're actually _subsets_) are just binary numbers where each digit is a 0 if the item is _not included_ in the subset and a 1 if the item _is included_ in the subset.  Put all those bits in order to form a binary number in the usual way, and then simply _add one_ to get the next subset.

Comment: the solution, you selected has a different sort order, than asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert any subset into a number (technically a `BigInt`) and any number back into a subset like this:

```
const toNumber = (s, arr) => 
  arr.reduce((a, v, i) => a | (s.includes(v) ? 1n << BigInt(i) : 0n), 0n);

const toSubset = (n, arr) => 
  arr.filter((e, i) => n & 1n << BigInt(i));
```

Then generating the so-called "next" subset is as easy as first converting the current subset to a number, then adding `1n` then converting back to a subset.

#### Complete example:

```js
const toNumber = (s, arr) =>
  arr.reduce((a, v, i) => a | (s.includes(v) ? 1n << BigInt(i) : 0n), 0n);

const toSubset = (n, arr) =>
  arr.filter((e, i) => n & 1n << BigInt(i));

const nextSubset = (s, arr) =>
  toSubset(toNumber(s, arr) + 1n, arr);


const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let subset = [];
while (true) {
  subset = nextSubset(subset, arr);
  if (subset.length == 0) break;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(subset));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a recursive function to generate all possible subarrays. And put in a base condition where if your argument array == to the function array, then return the next result.

```
function getSubArrays(arr, yourArray){
  if (arr.length === 1 || areArraysEqual(arr,yourArray)) return [arr];
  else {
    subarr = getSubArrays(arr.slice(1));
    return subarr.concat(subarr.map(e => e.concat(arr[0])), [[arr[0]]]);
  }
}

function areArraysEqual(arr,yourArray){
   //logic to check if arrays are equal
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are going for. But if the original array gets longer it will be kind of ineffecient to iterate all subarrays intill you find your current one.

Comment: Thats true, its just kind of impossible to predict what our result will look like without actually iterating through all of the subarrays.

Comment: I would not say impossible, check my edit

Answer (score 0):

You could take an abstract solution for the wanted order of combinations with `n` choose `k`, a row of a [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), where you find the count of items `k` to disperse.

After having this, you get a smaller set by recursion with checking `n - 1` choose `k - 1` for checking the given nth element and if this is smaller than the offset take `1` (`true`), if not `0` (`false`).

To get a wanted result take the nth element, add one, because this algorithm respects an empty set and get a result like this:

```text
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

which reads as follow, take elements at index three, four and five.

Full example for 5 elements:

```text
 0  00000  5 choose 0
   
 1  10000  5 choose 1 (5) -> 4 choose 0 (1)
 2  01000
 3  00100
 4  00010
 5  00001
   
 6  11000  5 choose 2 (10) -> 4 choose 1 (4)
 7  10100
 8  10010
 9  10001
10  01100                     4 choose 2 (6)
11  01010
12  01001
13  00110
14  00101  example 1
15  00011

16  11100  5 choose 3 (10) -> 4 choose 2 (6)
17  11010
18  11001
19  10110
20  10101
21  10011
22  01110
23  01101  example 2
24  01011
25  00111

26  11110
27  11101
28  11011
29  10111
30  01111

31  11111  2 ** 5 - 1
```

The code below contains two function which allows to use an array of boolean/0/1 values and get a number and from this number and with a given length of the array it returns the array of number, denoting values at indices.

For example take an array an get the number of it and get the array of the following combination.

```js
const
    add = (a, b) => a + b,
    factorial = n => +!n || n * factorial(n - 1),
    choose = (n, k) => factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k)),
    getC = (n, k, nth) => {
        if (n <= 0 || k <= 0) return Array(n).fill(0);

        let offset = choose(n - 1, k - 1);

        return nth < offset
            ? [1, ...getC(n - 1, k - 1, nth)]
            : [0, ...getC(n - 1, k, nth - offset)];
    },
    getCombination = (n, nth) => {
        let k = 0;

        while (k < n) {
            const value = choose(n, k);
            if (nth < value) break;
            nth -= value;
            k++;
        }

        return getC(n, k, nth);
    },
    getNumber = array => {
        let k = array.reduce(add, 0),
            n = array.length,
            nth = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) nth += choose(n, i);

        for (let i = 0, l = array.length - 1; i < l; i++) {
            if (!k) break;
            n--;
            if (array[i]) k--;
            else nth += choose(n, k - 1);
        }

        return nth;
    };

console.log(getNumber([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])); // 105
console.log(...getCombination(7, 105));        // [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
console.log(...getCombination(7, 106));        // [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thats really cool, nerver heard of Pascals Triangle before. Thanks!

Comment: @argrejer1, i read the question agan. mabe this answer does not answer the question. do you have want from a given pattern the next one? please add some more examples what the question is about.

Comment: I guess

`for (let i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
   console.log(arr.filter((e, index) => getCombination(arr.length, i)[index] === 1));
}`

would produce the same result as the code in my edit. Performance wise it is alot slower tho and in my case I would prefer the array containing the previous indexes as input instead of the 'nth' index but thats maybe something that can be fixed.

Comment: actually it takes an array and produces the number or take a length of array and a number and get the array.